# One way analysis of variance in Regression Model perspective

Tags: regression, linear-regression, regression-analysis, anova

Recently, I have some trouble with One-way ANOVA. Before I raise my doubts, I think it is necessary to make some notation.

Suppose that the form of One-way analysis of variance is as follows:
\begin{cases}
y_{ij}&=\mu_j+\epsilon_{ij}\quad i\in\{1,2,\cdots,n_j\},\ j\in\{1,2,\cdots,g\}\\
\epsilon_{ij}&\sim N(0,\sigma^2)\qquad\rm i.i.d
\end{cases}

$y_{ij}$:observations
$\mu_j$: the mean of the observations for the jth treatment group
$i$: the index over experimental units(Fix the group $j$, $i$ ranges from 1 to $n_j$)
$j$: the index over treatment groups(from $1$ to $g$)

If we regard the above model as a regression model, we can use dummy variables to construct the explanatory variables, and just like this:
\begin{cases}
\vec{y}=X\vec{\mu}+\vec{\epsilon}\\
\vec{\epsilon}\sim N(\vec{0},\sigma^2I_n)
\end{cases}

$\vec{y}=\begin{pmatrix}
\vec{y_1}\\
\vec{y_2}\\
\vdots\\
\vec{y_g}
\end{pmatrix}$,$\quad$ $X=\begin{pmatrix}
1_{n_1}& &\\
&1_{n_2}& &\\
& & \ddots&\\
& & & 1_{n_g}
\end{pmatrix}$,$\quad$$\vec{\mu}=\begin{pmatrix}
\mu_1\\
\mu_2\\
\vdots\\
\mu_g\\
\end{pmatrix}$.

$1_{n_j}$: a $n_j$-dimensional column vector of all 1s.

The OLS estimation of explanatory variables in this form is very simple because the design matrix X is a diagonal matrix. By using the results of $\hat{\mu}=(X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}\vec{y}=(\frac{1}{n_1}1_{n_1}^T\vec{y_{n_1}},\frac{1}{n_2}1_{n_2}^T\vec{y_{n_2}},\cdots,\frac{1}{n_g}1_{n_g}^T\vec{y_{n_g}})^T=(\overline{y}_{n_1},\overline{y}_{n_2},\cdots,\overline{y}_{n_g})^T$.

Since the one-way variance model can also be written in the form of an effects model, it can be considered as a regression model with an intercept term. But my question is how can I estimate the parameters of this model, especially it is too hard for me to derive the inverse of $(X^{T}X)^{-1}$, I hope someone can help me out.

Here is my thought:
The form of effects model is just like this:

\begin{cases}
y_{ij}&=\mu+\alpha_j+\epsilon_{ij}\quad i\in\{1,2,\cdots,n_j\},\ j\in\{1,2,\cdots,g\}\\
\epsilon_{ij}&\sim N(0,\sigma^2)\qquad\rm i.i.d
\end{cases}

$\mu$: the grand mean of observations
$\alpha_j=\mu_j-\mu$: the jth treatment effect, a deviation from the grand mean

In order to avoid the collinearity problem of the design matrix, $\alpha_j$ s is usually constrained as $\sum_{i=1}^{g}\alpha_i=0$. We can also use the regression model to describe this. Note that $\alpha_j$can be shown as $-\sum_{i=1}^{g-1}\alpha_i$.
\begin{cases}
\vec{y}=X\vec{\alpha}+\vec{\epsilon}\\
\vec{\epsilon}\sim N(\vec{0},\sigma^2I_n)
\end{cases}

$\vec{y}=\begin{pmatrix}
\vec{y_1}\\
\vec{y_2}\\
\vdots\\
\vec{y_g}
\end{pmatrix}$,$\quad$ $X=\begin{pmatrix}
1_{n_1}&1_{n_1}& &\\
1_{n_2}&&1_{n_2}& &\\
\vdots& & & \ddots&\\
1_{n_g}&-1_{n_g}&-1_{n_g} &\cdots & -1_{n_{g-1}}
\end{pmatrix}$,$\quad$$\vec{\mu}=\begin{pmatrix}
\mu\\
\alpha_1\\
\vdots\\
\alpha_{g-1}\\
\end{pmatrix}$.

In this way, we can also estimate the $\vec{\alpha}$ theoretically, but how to derive the inverse of $(X^TX)^{-1}$?